# What is the interface name for a USB modem?

Tags: networking, network-interface, mobile

I need to use `vnstat` to check the data usage of the USB modem (mobile broadband) with a sim card. 
The usual interfaces names are: `eth0`, `wlan0`, and etc. 
I can't figure out what is the name of this modem to use for the command 
`vnstat -l -i`. I tried with `usb0`, `ttyusb0`, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I used the command `ifconfig` and see the device in use is `tun0`

To view all the available interfaces on the system that vnStat can monitor you can use the command `vnstat --iflist`

I then created a new database for the selected interface with `sudo vnstat -u -i tun0`